# What is meant by -> '$.CPT_CODE' in MySql trim

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql trim function in this way

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM billing_charge_procedures.cpt_code -> '$.CPT_CODE')
           AS Procedure_Code
FROM billing_charge_procedures
```

But I am getting this error

> [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '> '$.CPT_CODE')

I tried to browse what is **-> '$.CPT_CODE'** this in trim function. But got nothing about that.

There is **cpt_code** field in **billing_charge_procedures** table.

Sample data of **cpt_code** field is:

```
{"CPT_CODE":"74150","CPT_DESC_SHORT":" CT abdomen w\/o dye","CPT_DESC_LONG":" CT abdomen w\/o dye","is_selected":""}
```

Comment: So `cpt_code` is a JSON datatype column

Comment: What version of mariaDB are you using

Comment: Try `SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM (billing_charge_procedures.cpt_code -> '$.CPT_CODE') )`. But better try [JSON_UNQUOTE()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_unquote/).

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes. cpt_code is a JSON datatype column.

Comment: @Akina it's not working.  It through the same error

Comment: What is your MySQL version? PS. The code is correct: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8960f81d483bed0b584b6b1c368becb6).

Comment: @Akina Server version: 10.4.11-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: This version (or MariaDB at all?) does not support `->` operator it seems (it is not listed in "Function and Operator Reference"). Use `JSON_VALUE()`: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=5b3c961b5131ea3a67836cc5b26ee675)

Comment: @Akina Thanks. `JSON_VALUE()` worked for me.